# Add a Shared Project to a new solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have quite a large solution with many parts of our project in it. When I'm working on a single part I really don't need the other parts loaded into memory, much less taking up code analysis resources or accidentally getting built if I hit "build all".

As such, I've decided to create a new sub-solution which contains the subset of projects I'm working with (dependencies and such) for a specific product I'm working on. It happens to be a Universal Windows Phone 8.1 application which has a shared project with our Universal Windows 8.1.

So far, I've created a new empty solution and added all of the dependencies necessary to it. It builds just fine. The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to add the shared project to the solution.

I.e., if our projects are `Example.WinRT`, `Example.WinRT.Phone`, and `Example.WinRT.Shared`, then I can add .WinRT and .WinRT.Phone just fine, (and they build), but I cannot add .WinRT.Shared. This is obviously a problem because there are files in the shared project that I need to be editing.

How can I add both projects to the new solution?

Answer (score 1):

I came to a realization and figured this out just as I was finishing up the question. I figured I'd still answer it so others can see.

The key is to add the Shared project *before* adding in the other depending projects.

So the order is:

1. Create the new Solution.
2. Add `Example.WinRT.Shared` to the solution.
3. Add `Example.WinRT` and `Example.WinRT.Phone` to the solution.

In this way your new solution can have all of the necessary projects in it.

Hope this helps.